How to localize fields that have an options list in Sanity?
I have this field in a Sanity project:

I would like the options to appear on Sanity Studio in French instead of English when editing the French localization. However, I have not found a way to do this and it is not mentioned in the Localization documentation page.
I have tried implementing localization using the document-level translations method but I can't find a way to show different options depending on the document language.
